# Update battery level through service class as background process

Tags: android, android-service, android-background

Hello friends I'm developing an Battery android application. which show battery level(%) on Status bar after closing application. I start an service class that run as background process and put some code.
 Notificationservice.java

```
 public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        IntentFilter filter= new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        Intent batteryStatus= getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null, filter);
        int status= batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        batteryLevel= String.valueOf(status);

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //make the toast message
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started"+batteryLevel+"%", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //show the notification on status bar
    NotificationManager nm=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent2= new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mbuilder= new 
            NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle("Battery Level: "+batteryLevel+"%")
    .setContentText("Battery Level: "+batteryLevel+"%")
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    nm.notify(notificationID, mbuilder.build());
    return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "service Destroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

In MainActivity.java

```
rotected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    createListener();
}


private void createListener() {
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Notificationservice.class));
        }
    });

    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Notificationservice.class));

        }
    });

}
```

When I press run application run properly but when I press start Service  button battery level shows on status bar but it doesn't change/update it remains same. friends please help, what should I do....???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to start the service or notification from broadcast receiver..just register a broadcast to get battery level..and from onreceive() method of receiver..call notification or start a service..

Comment: I get the battery level and start a service it show notifucation of my battery level. But it not get update(like if I start service at 25℅ it show notification your battery level is 25℅ it doesn't get update/change)

Comment: Yes I know, I have to update my notification continuously with same ID then it will get update, but I don't know how to implement it if you have any idea/solution please share.